# I want to run a thread in my application that will run for the entire time while the user is online. I cant choose variant

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to prevent the thread from stopping during the transition between activities and call this thread during the start of my application. I have one option and I would like to share it. So far, I have stopped at writing an android service in which to include the beginning of the stream that, I need to perform. And then call it in the class inherited from the application class. It is important to note that my thread will send certain data to the database every minute. Perhaps you can advise a more reliable and popular way to solve the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Threads don't stop between Activities.  That would be impossible to do safely-  threads cannot in general be safely stopped by anyone but the thread itself without risk of data corruption or deadlock.  So Android doesn't even try.  (You can cancel a thread from another thread, but that works by setting a flag and hoping that the thread you want to cancel looks at it occasionally to honor it.)

The real problem is twofold

1)How do you know if the thread is already running so you don't launch it again.  This is solvable in a variety of way.

2)Do you want the thread to work when the app is in the background?  This is the real problem, because Android kills background apps regularly, which will end the thread.  There is no reliable way to make a thread run constantly in the background in Android.  Here your best bets are either a foreground service running to keep the app active, or to not use a thread and make your app even t driven (for example, setting a repeating alarm for every 15 minutes and running then).

Comment: no no no I want the stream to work only when the user's application is currently running. and the flow stops when the application finishes its activity